# CSS Marquee for variable message lengths

Tags: html, css, marquee

I am looking for marquee tag alternatives and found how to do this through css. However the messages I am using are of variable lengths, so is there an alternative to putting in the '45s' attribute to maybe 100% so that no matter how long or short the message is, the message will show all of the message and loop again once the message has been displayed?

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #000000;
  font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;  /* show the marquee just outside the paragraph */
  animation: marquee 45s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes marquee {
  from  { text-indent:  0%}
  to    { text-indent: -150% }
}
```

```html
<p id="PassengerNews_Scrollbar" class="microsoft marquee" style="height: 95%;  width: 90%;left: 5%;top: 2%;font-size: 7%;">
  <span>|*NewsData*|</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Not with CSS. You'd need a variable and that's the purview of JS.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jQuery.Marquee](https://github.com/aamirafridi/jQuery.Marquee) plugin  (License: [ISC](https://tldrlegal.com/license/-isc-license)). If you don't want to use the plugin, you can use following code snippet from the plugin to calculate the delay

```
// formula is to: (Width of the text node + width of the main container / Width of the main container) * speed;
o.duration = ((parseInt(elWidth, 10) + parseInt(containerWidth, 10)) / parseInt(containerWidth, 10)) * o.duration;
```

With o.duration initialized with `5000` meaning 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

you want something like this?

```css
.marquee {
    margin: 0 auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: Arial Rounded MT Bold;
    
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    top: 5%;
    font-size: 7%;
}
.marquee .line__wrap {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    left: 0;
    animation: marquee__wrap 2s linear infinite;
    
    font-size: 18px;
}
.marquee .line {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -100%;
    animation: marquee 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes marquee__wrap {
    from {
        margin-left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        margin-left: 0%;
    }
}
@keyframes marquee {
    from {
        left: 100%;
    }
    to {
        left: 0%;
    }
}
```

```html
<p id="PassengerNews_Scrollbar" class="microsoft marquee">
    <span class="line__wrap">
        <span class="line">|*NewsData*|</span>
    </span>
    
    <span class="line__wrap" style="top: 30px;">
        <span class="line">|*NewsData*|long long long long massage</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: If you add more "long"s to the "long message", the text speed increases. This is not what is desired. The speed should remain constant.